# iOS Calendar View day component

Tags: ios, calendar, components, icalendar

I'm looking for a component which allows me to manage a calendar daily view like in iCal. So far,I've found https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui
The problem is that a simple way to create an event by tapping is missing. Writing a procedure for creating an event by tapping, managing at the same time dragging and extension of the event view may be quite time consuming. Do you know if any component (open source or commercial) implementing this feature is available somewhere? I don't think iOS provides anything like that.

Comment: how about this: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ckcalendar?

Comment: I think it's only for the monthly view. I need the day view.

Comment: oops sorry... then i am not sure...

Comment: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kal how abt this? you still need to customise it accordingly...

Comment: Again,I think this is just month view. I have found another one: https://github.com/guicocoa/calendar but it doesn't implement the event creating by touch

Comment: i think that's the point... you got to customise that part yourself...

Comment: it looks like there is no choice...

Answer (score 0):

The best one I have found so far is: [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar)